# can i share streamlit web app locally without publishing to github/heroku?

Tags: python, streamlit

is anyone aware of method to share streamlit web app to others locally without publishing to heroku/github?

skimmed through internet and found out creating bat or exe file could be the alternatives but no comprehensive solution.

with regard to that, can anyone share detailed procedure on how to accomplish that ? many thanks

Sample 1

```
set root=C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\
call %root%\Scripts\activate.bat
call streamlit run "path\to\file\app.py"
```

Sample 2

```
@ECHO OFF
set root=C:\Anaconda3
call %root%\Scripts\activate.bat
cd [PATH_TO_YOUR_STREAMLIT_APP_FOLDER]
pip install -r requirements.txt
call streamlit run app.py
```

Comment: What non-comprehensive solutions did you find on the net? Please [edit] your question to include that, as then it becomes clear where your issue lies.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I have top up some coding samples there.

Comment: Ok, good first step, but why do these solutions not work for you?

Comment: clueless on how to make the start . create a text file for this or run on anaconda command prompt? where should i start ?

Comment: Ah I see, so you're issue is not with streamlit/Python/Anaconda, but you need to know how to run a .bat file. Perhaps this link helps? https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-and-run-batch-file-windows-10

Comment: The question is what kind of user the target is. If it's another coder, just create a requirements.txt file for your project and give them the source code (i.e. using an online repository like GitHub). Then they can recreate your environments and run the app via Streamlit locally themselves.
If the target user is not a coder, you need to package everything, i.e. in a Docker container (see i.e. official documentation here https://docs.streamlit.io/knowledge-base/tutorials/deploy/docker).

Comment: tried but to no avail. need guidance here.