# How to share streamlit app locally without github for coworkers to launch?

Tags: streamlit

I'd like to easily share my Streamlit apps to co-workers. Some of the requirements that I have:

- I want the app to be run locally because we are tackling confidential data
- No need to go through Github
- Co-workers are able to launch the app without Python code

How can I accomplish this?

Is creating exe or bat file feasible in this case?

```
Install Nativefier npm install -g nativefier
Run nativefier --name '<you .exe name>' '<your streamlit sharing website url>' --platform <'windows' or 'mac' or 'linux'>
```

Comment: How is this question different from your question from 2 hours ago?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74635228/can-i-share-streamlit-web-app-locally-without-publishing-to-github-heroku

Comment: where to install nativefier?